# Which frames are more suited for PvE?

Tags: firefall

This question may be based on opinion (and if it is close it, I wont be mad), but I was wondering which battleframes are "clearly" designed more for PvE or PvP. For example, the Nighthawk Recon is better designed for PvE due to its AOE abilities and explosive sniper rifle. I was wondering if the same could be said for all the frame types, one is more for PvE while the other is more for PvP.

Comment: I believe this is rather opinion-based.  An argument could be made for good subjective, though, so long as answerers back up their claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer is outdated by a year. Almost everything has changed since then, so it's probably not a good idea to follow anymore.**

Some 'frames carry wide area-of-effect abilities that are quite well-suited for onslaughts of enemies common in PvE, while others use hard-to-aim but powerful single-target attacks. Thus, it is reasonable to assume that there some are better in PvE than others, to various degrees.

'frames favouring PvE: Firecat, Nighthawk, Bastion.

'frames favouring PvP: Tigerclaw, Raptor, Electron.

Dreadnought and Biotech 'frames don't seem to have such a pronounced difference.

However, this only applies to stock equipment. Since you can use Accord components on Astrek and ODM 'frames. With this sort of mix-and-matching, it's entirely possible to turn a supposedly PvP 'frame into one that has no problem defending thumpers and fighting the Chosen.

And of course, every 'frame can be played well in PvP. Player skill is the deciding factor here.

Comment: See, we already disagree about Recons. I suppose they do about the same in PvE and I just like the Nighthawk better.

Comment: your mention of brands brings up another point. I might save that for another question, but basically. does brand define what it is? (ODM = PvE?)

Comment: It's just flavour. Astrek 'frames do tend to favour offence, finesse and playing against archetype, while ODM favour defence, power and supporting the archetype. Accord battleframes are balanced. Interesting bit of trivia and insight into the game's lore (possibly Red5's design process as well), doesn't really come up in gameplay.

Comment: This answer should probably be updated. A lot has changed in the last year, including that there are 16 battleframes now.

Comment: @Brian You are right, but those changes have also reduced my interest in the game. And for most of the intervening time, there wasn't even a PvP to worry about. So go ahead and post your own, I suppose.

Comment: @Pvt.Grichmann I haven't played enough to post my own. Hopefully someone who has enough experience with the recent versions of the game will post an updated answer.